# How do I avoid destructor stack overflow with deep nested data structure in C++?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, destructor

```
int count;

class MyClass {
    std::shared_ptr<void> p;
public:
    MyClass(std::shared_ptr<void> f):p(f){
        ++count;
    }
    ~MyClass(){
        --count;
    }
};

void test(int n){
    std::shared_ptr<void> p;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        p = std::make_shared<MyClass>(p);
    }
    std::cout<<count<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    test(200000);
    std::cout<<count<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above program causes stack overflow under "release" build in Visual Studio 2010 IDE.

The question is: if you do need to create some data structure like the above, how to avoid this problem.

UPDATE: Now I have seen one meaningful answer. However this is not good enough. Please consider I have updated `MyClass` to contain two (or more) `shared_ptr`s, and each of them can be an instance of `MyClass` or some other data.

UPDATE: Somebody updated the title for me and saying "deep ref-counted data structure", which is not necessary related to this question. Actually, `shared_ptr` is only a convenient example; you can easily change to other data types with the same problem. I also removed the `C++11` tag because it is not C++11 only problem as well.

Comment: Have you set break points to determine which line it is crashing on?

Comment: How to avoid it if you do have a deep recursive data structure?

Comment: @EarthEngine ...by avoid doing deep recursive structures...

Comment: @druciferre In case of "stack overflow" crash, usually the IDE can clearly tell you at least which function(s) is going wrong. So diagnose is not the point.

Comment: @AndersK You are definitely right. However, consider the data was created from some user input, and the programmer forgotten this possibility, you will agree this is a potential security issue.

Comment: There is no reason for your destructor to be causing a stack overflow. Do you know how many iterations your app goes through before the overflow occurs? I still strongly recommend that you set some break points and pinpoint the exact line where the crash happens.

Comment: @druciferre If you debug in the IDE for just a few minutes, you can see how the stack filled by destructor calls.

Comment: @EarthEngine: Updating a question to invalidate answers is not good. In those cases it's better to ask a new question (with updated code too) that can be answered correctly (and probably a bit differently). If you just think an answer (i.e. mine) is limiting, add a comment and explain what you're missing.

Answer (score 2):

- Make the stack explicit (i.e. put it in a container on the heap).
- Have non-opaque pointers (non-void) so that you can walk your structure.
- Un-nest your deep recursive structure onto the heap container, making the structure non-recursive (by disconnecting it as you go along).
- Deallocate everything by iterating over the pointers collected above.

Something like this, with the type of p changed so we can inspect it.

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> p;

~MyClass() {
    std::stack<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> ptrs;
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> current = p;

    while(current) {
        ptrs.push_back(current);
        current = current->p;
        ptrs.back()->p.reset(); // does not call the dtor, since we have a copy in current
    }

    --count;
    // ptrs dtor deallocates every ptr here, and there's no recursion since the objects p member is null, and each object is destroyed by an iterative for-loop
}
```

Some final tips:

- If you want to untangle any structure, your types should provide an interface that returns and releases all internal shared_ptr's, i.e something like: `std::vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>> yieldSharedPtrs()`, perhaps within a ISharedContainer interface or something if you can't restrict yourself to MyClass.
- For recursive structures, you should check that you don't add the same object to your ptr-container twice.

Comment: This program is incorrect. `p` is not a member of `std::shared_ptr<void>`.

Comment: @EarthEngine: Yeah. Sorry. But obviously you can't untangle an opaque ptr (i.e. shared_ptr<void>), since you don't know anything about it. You must use some kind of typing. I've expanded my answer to explain about that, and fixed the code a bit more.

Comment: I found a way that do not require knowing the actual type of the opaque ptr. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Macke's tips, I have an improved solution like the following:

```
~MyClass(){
   DEFINE_THREAD_LOCAL(std::queue< std::shared<void> >, q)
   bool reentrant = !q.empty();
   q.emplace(std::move(p)); //IMPORTANT!
   if(reentrant) return;

   while(!q.empty()){
       auto pv = q.front();
       q.pop();
   }
}
```

`DEFINE_THREAD_LOCAL` is a macro that defines a variable (param 2) as specified type (param 1) with thread local storage type, which means there is no more than one instance for each running thread. Because `thread_local` keyword is still not available for mainstream compilers, I have to assume such a macro to make it work for compilers.

For single thread programs, `DEFINE_THREAD_LOCAL(type, var)` is simply

```
static type var;
```

The benefit of this solution is it do not require to change the class definition.

Unlike @Macke's solution, I use `std::queue` rather than `std::stack` in order to keep the destruction order.

In the given test case, `q.size()` will never be more than 1. However, it is just because this algorithm is breadth-first. If `MyClass` has more links to another instance of `MyClass`, `q.size()` will reach greater values.

NOTE: It is important to remember use std::move to pass p to the queue. You have not solved the problem if you forgotten to do so, you are just creating and destroying a new copy of p, and after the visible code the destruction will still be recursive.

UPDATE: the original posted code has a problem: `q` is going to be modified within `pop()` call. The solution is cache the value of `q.front()` for later destruction.

Answer (score -1):

If you really have to work with such an odd code, you can increase the size of your stack. You should find this option in the project properties of Visual Studio.

As already suggested, I must tell you that this kind of code should be avoided when working with a large mole of data structures, and increasing the stack size is not a good solution if you plan to release your software. It may also terribly slow down your own computer if you abuse this feature, obviously.

Comment: "odd" code? This is just a simple "linked list" example, and 200000 nodes is not big enough for many applications.

Comment: @EarthEngine yeah, odd. Don't take it as an insult, I meant that it is not well designed. If you have to manage such a great number of structures, you should avoid recursion, as it fills your stack.

Comment: It's pretty odd to be storing them this way, specifically because it doesn't work well. The typical way to fix this is to replace the implicit stack with an explicit stack, as in Macke's answer.

Comment: It's quite natural when the data structure is extracted from the user input, say, IR from some source code provided by the user. On the opposite, it *is* C++ being odd to force the users of the language to encode immature solutions in the program. Note that the native stack overflow cannot even be *detected* in a portable way, and the stack space can be *arbitrarily small* in a conforming implementation, so it is impossible to be totally avoided unless everything consuming the stack space is preserved statically (e.g. simply making no use of automatic objects at all), which sounds absurd.